# REVERSE PSYCHOLOGY

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

Transcript:

```
Colors:
W - White
K - Black
Y - Yellow
O - Orange
R - Red
G - Green
B - Blue
P - Purple
C - Cyan

WCWCWCWCWC
CBYKRRORBW
WBGRKKYWBC
CBYPKWYKBW
WBKYPORKBC
CBWWYBKRBW
WBKKYKBRBC
CBWRORRBBW
WBKKKKKKBC
CWCWCWCWCW
```

```
Letters:

RIEDVOENRT
KVSNRESDVS
EE HOTMPEN
ORA TSRTRY
CTHT NEETW
WIHOILTRIL
OCAGESORCH
AAGIYNGLAY
GL      LT
TOOTSCAHYA
```

Hint:

> The title is useful... but only if you've seen my earlier puzzles.

**The solution is a sequence of three letters.**

Partial solutions and ideas are welcome in either the comment section or the answer section.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Looks like a great first question :) To clarify, this is your own puzzle, right?

Comment: What makes you think it is not? @justhalf It is my own puzzle yes. Also it isn't my first question and imho it isn't as great as my previous ones.

Comment: Oh, was just clarifying, hehe, quite standard question for new comers here. Apologies, I haven't seen your previous question. Ah, all of them new questions, that's why I haven't seen them.

Comment: Now that you mention I understand... Got people coming in here with puzzles from other places they can't solve yah?

Comment: yep, and some even posting puzzles from on-going competitions, which is not allowed. More info on the [help page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For new users usually people will ask these questions to confirm, just to make sure. You're good!

Comment: Any thoughts on this puzzle? It's a relatively simple one, but I think I should add a hint for what the solution looks like...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150963/discussion-between-sny-smartie-and-justhalf).

Comment: @SnySmartie: It's a cool puzzle, as far as I'm concerned :)

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

> **SNY** - part of your username (Sny Smartie)

To see this, note...

> ...the [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) tag, and the irony of the title. In most of your other puzzles posted so far you emphasise that the colour choices are unimportant, but this time *they are*.

Focus first on...

> ...just the squares with a red component i.e. those coloured red, purple (red+blue) or orange (red+yellow). This forms the shape of an 'S':
>
>  [image: S traced out in red]
>
>  Then look at the squares with a blue component i.e. those coloured blue, purple (blue+red) or green (blue+yellow). This forms the shape of an 'N':
>
>  [image: N traced out in blue]
>
>  Then, finally, look at the squares with a yellow component i.e. those coloured yellow, orange (yellow+red) or green (yellow+blue). This forms the shape of a 'Y':
>
>  [image: Y traced out in yellow]
>
>  This gives us our answer: **SNY**.

Note that there were plenty of red herrings in the grid.

> If we had read off the letters written in particular colours, we would have seen the following unhelpful messages (punctuation added):
>
>  Cyan: I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO SAY
>  White: REVERSE PSYCHOLOGY, GOTCHA!
>  Red: RED HERRING
>  Blue: VERTICAL (twice) and LOL
>  Yellow: SMARTIE (another part of the OP's username)
>
>  And the following useful one:
>
>  Black: NOT[E] THE TAGS (the 'E' is actually a 'T' in the image), which would have led us to think *visually* this time instead of focussing on the printed letters themselves.
>
>  Also, the answer was hidden in plain sight too: the Orange letters actually spell out SNY.

Comment: Exactly correct! The black error was a mistake on my part.